# How do I share a private playlist I have created in YouTube with just a few friends?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have created a playlist of videos on YouTube that I have not made public.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need to change the privacy setting of the playlist to "Unlisted". Then you'll be able to share a URL with anyone who you want to be able to access the playlist. The playlist won't show up in search, so only those with the URL will be able to access it. You can change the setting back to "Private" again and then no one will be able to reach it again.

Comment: this seems more like a hack than a real solutions...

Comment: the issue is that if the videos are private and the playist is unlisted, then its silly to even share the playlist

Comment: @Charlie: The only way to share a private playlist is to make it not private. Do you have an alternate solution?

Comment: Do the videos remain private even if playlist remains unlisted? If so then I guess its ok to make the playlist unlisted.

Comment: YouTube needs to expand what private can mean. Only visible to you, or only visible to you and a select group of friends. I've made huge private playlist on my account and I'd like to share it with just friends, not the entire world. Playlists are just a list of links to videos, not videos themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You view your full playlist then you copy the search bar and send it to your friends, paste it and make it into a link for them.